# What is the correct way to build a URL to a Salesforce record from an external system?

Tags: url, navigation

We have multiple external systems that have access to our Salesforce record IDs & we'd like to build links from those external systems to our Salesforce records.  What is the correct way to do that?

Should we just navigate to the Id of the record (like we used to do in Classic)?  https://testdotcom.my.salesforce.com/TEST_ID_HERE

Or should we use the view URL for Lightning?  https://testdotcom.my.salesforce.com/lightning/r/Account/RECORD_ID_HERE/view

Are there other options?  What are the pros & cons of each approach?  Is there an official Salesforce guide that instructs us on how external sites  should build links to Salesforce records?

Comment: the latter would be problematic if the external system only had the ID;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply navigating to the record ID will suffice. The platform will automatically take the user to where they should be. Alternatively, if you retrieve the record details in the REST API,  you can use the URL provided to you.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox.  I also found the pageReference Types documentation helpful.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm