# URL link to SF record from external system - Not working for Field

Tags: lightning, html, redirect

I'm working on an external app and i'm trying to add a link there to salesforce records/objects.
When I'm trying to redirect the user to any record/object/user, I'm generating the URL like that: `https://${accountOrgUrl}.develop.my.salesforce.com/${resourceId}`.
So if I'm passing `resourceId` of user/record/object, I'm being redirected into the lightining dashboard,
and also to the right user/record/object page.
Only for "Field" I don't get this redirection.
For the field, I need to pass the full URL like: `${accountOrgUrl}/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/${subtypeName}/FieldsAndRelationships/${fieldId}/view`.
Can I somehow have a 1 link for all of the resources?
thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to build a URL to a Salesforce record from an external system?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/336921/what-is-the-correct-way-to-build-a-url-to-a-salesforce-record-from-an-external-s)

Comment: `...my.salesforce.com/${resourceId}` should read `...my.salesforce.com/${recordId}`. A field is not a record.

Comment: @identigral Thanks, It's exactly what I currently have and it's working to all of the records except for the `field`. I know that field is not a record - but it means that the redirection wouldn't work for "field"? I will need to create the full URL? `${accountOrgUrl}/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/${subtypeName}/FieldsAndRelationships/${fieldId}/view.`

Comment: Object record and field metadata are two very different types of info, thus "full URL" in the case of the latter. But sure, if you want to redirect them somewhere where they can see a field definition, you have it right.